# Probable false positive from Findbugs?

Tags: java, findbugs, java.util.concurrent

Please refer to the following code snippet(stripped off the redundant part to highlight the problematic case):

FindBugs is complaining that "*Method does not release lock on all paths*" . Is this a false positive? If not, how to fix this?

```
  try{
      someLock.lock();
     //do something
    } finally{
      if (someLock.isLocked())
        someLock.unlock();
    }
```

Comment: Why do you test ? You should do someLock.lock(); before the try.

Comment: @dystroy Even if the test is there why would there be an warning?

Comment: I don't know, I don't see a failing path, but this construct doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `isLocked()` throws something, then you don't unlock.

I don't think it's probable to have `isLocked` throwing an exception but when you lock, you must unlock, there is no point in testing. So why not use the standard pattern described in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) :

```
someLock.lock();
try{
    //do something
} finally{
    someLock.unlock();
}
```

So I'd said

- it's a false positive in the sense your code can't fail to unlock
- it's a true positive in the sense you should fix your code according to the recommendation

Answer (score 3):

**isLocked**

> Queries if this lock is held by any thread. This method is designed for use in monitoring of the system state, **not for synchronization control**.

Not being "for synchronization control" means that the implementation of **isLocked** is not guaranteed to be free from race conditions, and it may return false even if we have acquired the lock.

```
someLock.lock();
try{      
 //do something
} finally{
  someLock.unlock();
}
```

or

```
boolean locked=false;
try{      
 someLock.lock();
 locked=true;
 //do something
} finally{
  if (locked) someLock.unlock();
}
```

Comment: Well, this doesn't really explain the warning.

Comment: @dystroy I added some clarification. I think that Findbugs shows a warning becasue `isLocked` is not intended for synchronization control.

Comment: The second code seems useless : if you lock, you unlock, no need to test.

Comment: @dystroy If `lock()` is within the `try...finally` block; `lock()` may throw an (unchecked) exception and `finally` will be executed.

Comment: @Javier - This is why it's better to put the call to `lock` outside the `try` block.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a false positive, but I think I can understand why you get it.

The FindBugs rule is most likely coded to check that all paths call `unlock` ... irrespective of whether the call is actually needed (from the perspective of the lock's state).  It most likely does not make any attempt to track the state of the lock, and is most likely not aware of what `isLocked` *means*.  While it is obvious to you and I that it is unnecessary to call `unlock` if `isLocked` returns `false`, the FindBugs rule is not implemented to make this inference.

(Indeed, making the inference reliably in a wide range of use-cases would be a difficult problem for the FindBugs implementors.  We are in "automatic theorem prover" territory ...)